# Duplicate entries when displaying all columns from specific row (PHP/MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

Hello Fellow Stackers,

Appreciate if someone can help me with solving the following PHP/MYSQL issue.

Have a MYSQL database with hundreds of rows. For the sake of simplicity will focus on one record.

[image]

In my actual implementation each row has a different length of columns.

What I need to do is display these records on a webpage - please see below my MYSQL query and PHP code.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `dump` WHERE `COL 1` = 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<br />";

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
foreach($row as $value){
echo "$value <br />";
}
```

Here are my expected results.

Expected:

[image]

Unfortunately my results appear in duplicates.
Here are my actual results.

Actual:

[image]

Appreciate your input in resolving this issue.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You‘re fetching both types of an array: associative and numeric type.

So try to fetch only one of the types. You can use either

mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);

OR

mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

By omitting the 2nd parameter it defaults to this

mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);

Wich means you can access the column by number or by name. So all columns are provided 2 times.

See also: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Great, thank you. That has resolved the problem!                                                                               $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach($row as $value){
//print_r($row)
echo "$value <br />";
}